# Dgrid: ColumnHider plugin's 'hidden' property not taking effect

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have a column with with both 'hidden' & 'unhidable' set to true. However, the column does not hide....upon doing some testing, I found that it hides only when unhidable is set to false.

i.e.,

```
hidden: true,
unhidable: true
```

doesn't work

```
hidden: true,
unhidable: false
```

works

Is it not possible to have both hidden & unhidable as true?

FYI, I'm also using the ColumnResizer & DijitRegistry plugins. This is the column definition from the grid template:

```
<th data-dgrid-column='{
        field: "order",
        hidden: true,
        unhidable: true,
        sortable: false
        }'>
        Order
</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with the dgrid plugin & has now been fixed:

https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/199

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you don't need to unhide it later, you could solve it using the CSS approach?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .field-order {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```